# Is there a way to load a randomized bit of HTML into a div every 60 seconds in Javascript? (for advertisements)

Tags: javascript

To test different ads on my site, I need the page to randomly load one of 5 different ads every 60 seconds.

The HTML is like:

```
<div class="ads_right">

<script> ADVERTISEMENT CODE </script>

</div>
```

So, every 60 seconds it needs to  randomly load one of 5 different advertisement scripts in the `<div>`.

I'm not proficient in JavaScript, but this sort of thing is pretty straight forward in basically any language, C, PHP, etc. so if it's at all possible, would someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Would you please show how, Oram?

Comment: [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#setInterval())

Comment: I've read the page and understand how this would be useful in solving my problem. I'm so unpracticed with Javascript, and burned out trying to figure out how on Google that I'm in need of someone to write the code. Would you please write out the whole code needed to solve the problem, Oram? If you don't mind, I would really appreciate the favor, brother.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of ads and generate a random index inside [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#setInterval()).

```js
var ads = ["ad1", "ad2", "ad3"];
setInterval(function() {
  var element = document.querySelector('.ads_right');
  element.innerHTML = ads[Math.floor(Math.random() * ads.length)];
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div class="ads_right"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Oram. I greatly appreciate you taking the time to write this out. I have two more questions, if you don't mind?


How do I define the HTML for each part of the array?


Is the 2000 the interval in milliseconds? So for 60 seconds it would be 60000?

Comment: 1. you can put any string you want, including HTML. 2. yes, it's in milliseconds - just like it says in the documentation of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#setInterval())...